# Trigger the function of checked boxes to one button js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I wanted to if I could do this with only using javascript. I have a pdf links on each of my checkboxes. So if the selected checkboxes are checked then it would go to that links but only when the button is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='check[]']").bind("myCustomButtonClick", function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      item.siblings('a.dev-link').trigger('click');
    }
  });
})

$(document).on('click', '#dl-link', function() {
  $("input[name='check[]']").trigger("myCustomButtonClick");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="link" class="w-checkbox dl-check-wrap">
  <div class="w-checkbox-input w-checkbox-input--inputType-custom dl-check dev-check w--redirected-checked"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" data-name="check[]" id="mode">
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=17XNOXQ3dKZM9tznx4xGk8I0O5hcvw0kc" class="dl-link dev-link">Link</a>
  <span class="d-none w-form-label" for="check[]">Checkbox 4</span>
</label>

<a id="dl-link" href="#" class="dl-btn w-button">Download All</a>
```

Comment: Your code can be simplified, however my question is what are you expecting to happen when multiple checkboxes are checked? You can't send the user to more than one URL at a time...

Comment: You can not trigger more than one download at a time within the same window/tab. You would have to open each URL in a new popup (and hope that the browser's popup blocker doesn't block those.)

Comment: `bind` is deprecated in jquery 3 - you should use `on` instead

Comment: When you say "only when the button is clicked" do you mean "only when the box is checked"?